# Subtract from date in NLog configuration

Tags: date, dependency-injection, config, nlog, .net-4.8

I've configured NLog to archive the log files every day. It works, but the name of the created subdirectory for the archived log files contain the actual date, instead of the archived log's date.

If the current date is `2023.10.26` then NLog should create a subdirectory with name `archived-2023.10.25`
the first time the software is started on current day.

An important detail is that I don't want to add any date to the log file's name.

My `appsettings.json`:

```json
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    ...
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug"
    },
    "NLog": {
      "IncludeScopes": true,
      "RemoveLoggerFactoryFilter": true
    }
  },
  "NLog": {
    "autoShutdown": true,
    "autoReload": true,
    "throwConfigExceptions": true,
    "internalLogLevel": "Info",
    "internalLogFile": "c:\\temp\\internal-nlog.txt",
    "extensions": [
      { "assembly": "NLog.Extensions.Logging" }
    ],
    "variables": {
      "logPath": "D:\\Logs"
    },
    "targets": {
      "Info": {
        "type": "File",
        "createDirs": true,
        "layout": "${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${message}",
        "archiveEvery": "Day",
        "archiveFileName": "${logPath}\\Archive\\archived-${date:format=yyyy.MM.dd}\\Info.log",
        "fileName": "${logPath}\\Info.log"
      }
    },
    "rules": [
      {
        "logger": "Info",
        "minLevel": "Trace",
        "writeTo": "Info"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Registering NLog in `App.xaml.cs`

```cs
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host
    .CreateDefaultBuilder()
    .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, loggingBuilder) =>
    {
        loggingBuilder.AddNLog(
            new NLogProviderOptions() { ReplaceLoggerFactory = true },
            s => LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromSection(hostingContext.Configuration).LogFactory);
    })
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        // adding services
    })
    .Build();
```

Using a custom layout renderer I could make it work, but I'd rather keep everything in the NLog configuration if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using version 5.2.5 NLog's dynamic archive mode does not suppport dynamic directory names yet (only file names).

The only viable way I found was to use a custom layout renderer.

```cs
[LayoutRenderer("archive-directory")]
public class ArchiveDirectoryLayoutRenderer : LayoutRenderer
{
    protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        builder.Append(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy.MM.dd"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NLog [does not support mixing](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target#dynamic-vs-static-archive-logic) 'dynamic-archive-mode' with 'static-archive-mode'.

Instead you could configure the FileTarget like this (Using `{#}`):

```json
      "LogFile": {
        "type": "File",
        "fileName": "${logPath}/Info.log"
        "archiveFileName": "${logPath}/Archive/archived-{#}/Info.log",
        "archiveDateFormat": "yyyy.MM.dd",
        "archiveNumbering": "Date",
        "archiveEvery": "Day"
      }
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/FileTarget-Archive-Examples

Comment: This just created a directory with this name: "archived-{#}"

Comment: I tried this and this only works if the numbering is used in the file name and not in the directory name. So "Info-{#}.log" works but "archived-{#}/Info.log" does not.

Comment: @tamas Probably a limitation in the NLog Archive Logic. You are wellcome to create a pull-request - https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pulls

Comment: I created the pull-request. The AppVeyor build failed but I don't think that was caused by my commit because a RestAPI was the faulty one. I'm unable to run your unit tests locally because I don't have .Net 6 and VS 22.